# Brightness issue in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, xfce, backlight

I have newly installed FreeBSD on my laptop and I installed xfce on it , and I cannot change my brightness with fn keys and even on terminal ,no command works (xbacklight retuns
"No outputs have backlight property")
and there is no variable for hw.acpi.brigthness or similar which i got to know online

Comment: This is the wrong site for this question. StackOverflow is about software development. This seems like a better fit for Super User or Unix & Linux SE.

Comment: Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or https://superuser.com/ I also suggest the FreeBSD forums.

Answer (score 1):

The brightness keys don't really work when installed. You can tinker with [acpi_ibm(4)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=acpi_ibm&sektion=4&manpath=freebsd-release-ports) and [acpi_video(4)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=acpi_video&sektion=4&manpath=freebsd-release-ports) if you're interested.

Brightness can be increased or decreased with `backlight -f /dev/backlight/backlight0 incr [value]` and `backlight -f /dev/backlight/backlight0 decr [value]` respectively. Check the man page of backlight for further information.

Add a key binding to make it work like fn keys.